# Centering an image horizontally using "center"

Tags: html, image, center

I'm having trouble centering an image horizontally. This is my code:

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="johnson johnson" style="width:300px; height:225px;" class="center">
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please include the HTML/CSS of the parent container where you want to center the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `left` & `right` `margin` to `auto`;

> **Solution:**
>
> `margin:0 auto;`
>
> `display:block`

```html
<div style="border:solid 1px red">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="johnson johnson" style="width:300px; height:225px;margin:0 auto;display:block">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add this

```
<style>
.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
</style>
```

I just create your class center to make it center the image

Comment: Am I supposed to create that center class? I thought I could just use "center" since I was under the impression that it already exists.

Comment: if you already created that class you can just check the class code inside your css

Comment: Please check you css file or <style></style> tag and check if this code already exists

Answer (score 1):

Just add p tag before image and add style to it.

```
 <p style="text-align:  center;">
     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="johnson johnson" style="width:300px;height:225px;>
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the styling **in-line**, you can use the **center tag**

```
<center>
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff" alt="johnson johnson" style="width:300px; height:225px;">
<center>
```